# Which unattended-upgrades system takes precedence and how?

Tags: package-management, security, unattended-upgrades

I've just run into an answer that has made me question *how* the unattended upgrade system works. There seem to be at least two systems on my computer:

1. `unattended-upgrades` with `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`, called from `/etc/cron.daily/apt`, and
2. The GUI Update Manager's settings (`software-properties-kde` et al). I don't know how this second system schedules or runs, but I have observed that changing the settings in the GUI does **not** update the settings in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`.

That leads me to believe that these are actually two competing systems. If correct, do they both run on their own schedule, or does one short-circuit the other? And how are the unattended update setting from the GUI Software Properties actioned?

Comment: Only 1 should be active. This is old: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates but seems still relevant(?)

Comment: Yup, that explains how the first works (which is fairly simple to follow through the scripts) but I don't understand how GUI version fits into any of that, or how one stops the other from running. I'm trying to work out what happens if one has all automatic updates turned on and the other has them turned off. Who wins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. CRON

   Excerpt of `/etc/cron.daily/apt`:

   ```
   # This file understands the following apt configuration variables:
   # Values here are the default.

   ...

   #  APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";
   #  - Run the "unattended-upgrade" security upgrade script 
   #    every n-days (0=disabled)
   #    Requires the package "unattended-upgrades" and will write
   #    a log in /var/log/unattended-upgrades

   ...

   UnattendedUpgradeInterval=0
   eval $(apt-config shell UnattendedUpgradeInterval APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade)

   ...

   # auto upgrade all upgradeable packages
   UPGRADE_STAMP=/var/lib/apt/periodic/upgrade-stamp
   if which unattended-upgrade >/dev/null && check_stamp $UPGRADE_STAMP $UnattendedUpgradeInterval; then
       if unattended-upgrade $XUUPOPT; then
           update_stamp $UPGRADE_STAMP
           debug_echo "unattended-upgrade (success)"
       else
           debug_echo "unattended-upgrade (error)"
       fi
   else
       debug_echo "unattended-upgrade (not run)"
   fi
   ```

   Description of package `unattended-upgrades`:

   > This package can download and install security upgrades automatically and unattended, taking care to only install packages from the configured APT source, and checking for dpkg prompts about configuration file changes.
   >
   > This script is the backend for the APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade option.

   The APT cron job runs `unattended-upgrade`, which is the program that downloads and installs the upgrades, but only if the APT variable `APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade` is not `0`.
2. Software Properties

   Settings for the options ***Automatically check for updates*** and ***When there are security updates*** are saved in the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`.

   ***Automatically check for updates*** maps to APT variable `APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists`.

   ***When there are security updates*** maps to variables `APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages` and `APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade`.

   Selecting ***Download and install automatically*** (the security updates)  will set `APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade` to 1. This is what tells the APT cron job to run `unattended-upgrade`, which performs all the package installation job.

   The Software Properties window only controls the schedule for these three APT's periodic tasks: check for updates, download upgradeable packages and run `unattended-upgrade`. It doesn't actually run anything, all the hard work is done by `/etc/cron.daily/apt` and `unattended-upgrade`.
3. `unattended-upgrade`

   The program that actually performs the upgrade task. The file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` holds the settings that affect the behavior of `unattended-upgrade`. It isn't read by any other program. If you want to customize how the upgrades are installed you have to manually edit this file.

There is only one unattended upgrade system (`unattended-upgrade`) that is called by the APT cron job (`/etc/cron.daily/apt`) only if we enable it via the Software Properties window (or manually editing `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`).

Comment: A Good one! ;-)